# Add tensorflow package at Electron project

Tags: tensorflow, webpack, electron

I tried to add some tensorflow package to electron project (which is [boilerplate project](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)), but errors come up like below. anyone know why and how to fix it? I'm working on window 10 environment.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.1.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^3.13.0",
```

This is how i added tensorflow package added, and blow is error message i've got.

```
$ npm install

> pmon@ postinstall C:\Users\DH\workspace\pmon
> ts-node .erb/scripts/check-native-dep.js && electron-builder install-app-deps && cross-env NODE_ENV=development TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack --config ./.erb/configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.ts && opencollective-postinstall

  • electron-builder  version=22.13.1
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • installing production dependencies  platform=win32 arch=x64 appDir=C:\Users\DH\workspace\pmon\release\app
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
| <html>
| <head>
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 81:13-36 286:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js 43:13-44
 @ dll renderer renderer[1]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js 43:20-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mock-aws-s3' in 'C:\Users\DH\workspace\pmon\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util'     
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 15:21-62
 @ ./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js 43:13-44
 @ dll renderer renderer[1]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js 76:14-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in 'C:\Users\DH\workspace\pmon\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util'
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 15:21-62
 @ ./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js 43:13-44
 @ dll renderer renderer[1]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js 112:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nock' in 'C:\Users\DH\workspace\pmon\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util'
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 15:21-62
 @ ./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js 43:13-44
 @ dll renderer renderer[1]

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/Find-VisualStudio.cs 9:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // This script needs to be compatible with PowerShell v2 to run on Windows 2008R2 and Windows 7.
|
> using System;
| using System.Text;
| using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./Find-VisualStudio.cs
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 81:13-36 286:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js 43:13-44
 @ dll renderer renderer[1]

webpack compiled with 5 errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pmon@ postinstall: `ts-node .erb/scripts/check-native-dep.js && electron-builder install-app-deps && cross-env NODE_ENV=development TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack --config ./.erb/configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.ts && opencollective-postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pmon@ postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-27T10_16_54_785Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, seems to be either an issue with the webpack loader or node-pre-gyp.